# Major programming languages on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, programming, language-support

I am a developer interested in moving (at least something like a dual boot) to Linux, specifically Ubuntu. I am interested in programming aspects of the OS, I know the majority of it is written in C and it's a great language to work with the OS, but are there any OS specific languages? Like how Windows has Batch (And Microsoft developing C#), and Mac has Swift, is there any language that is exclusive, or nearly exclusive for Ubuntu? What languages are most easily worked on in Linux environments?

Thanks!

Comment: short answer: Bash, although it is more of a scripting language

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux programs are written in C ([Here's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23635/229100) why), although Python is probably gaining a lot of popularity these days.

That being said, there is no exclusive language for Ubuntu. What I can think of that comes closest, is Bash. You can write scripts in Bash for certain jobs.
[Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala) also should count, but it's for Gnome developers in general.